# Handling argparse escaped character as option

Tags: python, delimiter, argparse

The argparse library handles escaped characters (like \t to tab and \n to newline) differently than I prefer. [An answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334965/parser-in-python3-does-not-take-delimiter-values-from-commandline-via-argparse) gives a solution but I would like to make it less visible to the user.

Given the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delimiter', default='\t')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

You will receive this output:

```
bash$ parser.py -d \t
Namespace(delimiter='t')

bash$ parser.py -d \\t
Namespace(delimiter='\\t')

bash$ parser.py -d '\t'
Namespace(delimiter='\\t')

bash$ parser.py -d '\\t'
Namespace(delimiter='\\\\t')

bash$ parser.py -d "\t"
Namespace(delimiter='\\t')

bash$ parser.py -d "\\t"
Namespace(delimiter='\\t')

bash$ parser.py -d $'\t'
Namespace(delimiter='\t')

bash$ parser.py -d $'\\t'
Namespace(delimiter='\\t')

bash$ parser.py -d $"\t"
Namespace(delimiter='$\\t')

bash$ parser.py -d $"\\t"
Namespace(delimiter='$\\t')
```

I get the desired argument only with

```
parser.py -d $'\t'
```

but I would prefer the input to look something like

```
parser.py -d \t
```

or less preferably

```
parser.py -d '\t'
parser.py -d "\t"
```

If I want to change the behavior, is this something I can do using the argparse library?
If not, is it possible for me to write the behavior on top of the existing argparse library?
If not, is this just the way that bash passes arguments to argparse therefore out of my hands?
If that is true, is this something that is usually documented to users or is this behavior assumed to be normal?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/ . In order to solve the problem, it is necessary to first *understand what data `argparse` will see*, and then decide how to process it. Python can't change how the shell interprets and tokenizes the input; it can only use `sys.argv` as it's provided.

Comment: This question was useful in pointing out that `parser.py -d $'\t'` worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string that you see in the `namespace` is exactly the string that appears in `sys.argv` - which was created by `bash` and the interpreter.  The `parser` does not process or tweak this string.  It just sets the value in the `namespace`.  You can verify this by print `sys.argv` before parsing.

If it is clear to you what the user wants, then I'd suggest modifying `args.delimiter` after parsing.  The primary purpose of the parser is to figure out what the user wants.  You, as programmer, can interpert and apply that information in any way.

Once you've worked out a satisfactory post-parsing function, you could implement it as a `type` for this argument (like what `int()` and `float()` do for numerical strings).  But focus on the post-parsing processing.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that the question was partially about how to carry out the post-processing explained by @hpaulj and since I couldn't see an immediate solution for Python 3 in the links above, here is a quick solution:

```
import codecs

def unescaped_str(arg_str):
    return codecs.decode(str(arg_str), 'unicode_escape')
```

then in the parser:

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delimiter', type=unescaped_str, default='\t')
```

This will make your less desirable cases work:

```
parser.py -d '\t'
parser.py -d "\t"
```

But not the desired unescaped `\t`. In any case, this solution can be dangerous as there is no check mechanism...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way to handle the quoted (`'\t'` and `"\t"`) input cases correctly (although it only specifically handles your specific tab case input):

```
parser.add_argument('-d', '--delimiter', type=lambda d: '\t' if d == '\\t' else d)
```

First note the following: in Python, `"\t"` is the tab literal, and the escaped `"\\t"` is a two-character string (the first character is `"\"`, and the second is `"t"`). You can check this with `len("\t"), len("\\t")`, which gives `1, 2`.

When the user gives the quoted `-d '\t'` on the command line, python will receive the string `'\t'` (literally the two characters, "backslash" and "t"). We want to replace this two-character string with a single "tab" character. The `type` argument takes a function as a way of pre-processing an argument. The lambda function checks for the two-character string and replaces it with the tab character.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just expect that behavior—your shell interprets some items and passes either a literal tab, or a backslash and a letter-t—and not necessarily want the Python program to do a second level of interpretation (and there's nothing in argparse to do it).

That said, though, Python has built in interpreters for this; see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885181/1256452).

Comment: Thanks for the note about expecting this as normal behavior. I've just documented it and will come back to it if a use complains